# Javascript: Convert a String to Regular Expression

Tags: javascript

I want to convert a string that looks like a regular expression...into a regular expression.

The reason I want to do this is because I am dynamically building a list of keywords to be used in a regular expression. For example, with file extensions I would be supplying a list of acceptable extensions that I want to include in the regex.

```
var extList = ['jpg','gif','jpg'];

var exp = /^.*\.(extList)$/;
```

Thanks, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll want to use the RegExp constructor:

```
var extList = ['jpg','gif','jpg'];    
var reg = new RegExp('^.*\\.(' + extList.join('|') + ')$', 'i');
```

[MDC - RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: Another way can be to use eval(...), but creating Regexp object is far way better solution.

Comment: a) `RegExp`, not `Regexp`; b) You created `/^.*.(jpg|gif|jpg)$/` (note the missing backslash); c) The third parameter is optional if you aren't going to pass any flags.

Comment: I noticed that this method does't accept regex's that start and end with a slash, ie `"/^b/"`. is there a way to account for this besides manually trimming the slashes. (The string coms from user input).

Answer (score 2):

```
var extList = "jpg gif png".split(' ');
var exp = new RegExp( "\\.(?:"+extList.join("|")+")$", "i" );
```

Note that:

- You need to double-escape backslashes (once for the string, once for the regexp)
- You can supply flags to the regex (such as case-insensitive) as strings
- You don't need to anchor your particular regex to the start of the string, right?
- I turned your parens into a non-capturing group, `(?:...)`, under the assumption that you don't need to capture what the extension is.

*Oh, and your original list of extensions contains 'jpg' twice :)*

Answer (score 1):

You can use the RegExp object:

```
var extList = ['jpg','gif','jpg'];

var exp = new RegExp("^.*\\.(" + extList.join("|") + ")$");
```